# Python stuck at Selenium webdriver.Chrome()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

After I import `webdriver` from `selenium` and call `webdriver.Chrome()`, Python gets stuck.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> d = webdriver.Chrome()
```

No output, no error messages, nothing. If I do:

```
> chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961)
```

this implies that chromedriver has been installed and is on `$PATH`.

Any idea why I'm stuck at `webdriver.Chrome()`?

Comment: Do you have chromium-browser installed on your system? If you don't the behavior is similar to what you describe I think.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same issue and it found out to be incompatible of the driver supported version and the chrome version.

In the [Downloads page in ChromeDriver website](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) lists the driver versions and the corresponding supported Chrome version. Make sure that the driver version is compatible to the Chrome version you're using.

By the way, the downloading page to previous versions is [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html). The page can be accessed by clicking the "Latest Release" link, then click the "Parent Dictionary". To me it's not that straightforward so I'll just leave a note here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used VS Code built-in terminal, the output just froze.

Changing in VS Code settings `terminal.integrated.rendererType` (can be found by search) from `auto` to `dom` solves the problem.